# how to add a new input as a dropdown type and with filled default options to laravel jetstream registration form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

my need is to add a new input as a dropdown type and with filled default options to laravel.8 jetstream registration form.
my problems are:

1. how to add dropdown input to the registration blade file? use jetstream component or have to create a new component based on livewire or pure laravel component?
2. where default options for dropdown must be prepare and sent to the blade file?
3. how can I get selected options from users in app/Actions/Fortify/CreateNewUser.php?
   thanks

Comment: Is it a requirement that you need to pass the dropdown values to ```register.blade.php```? Or can you initialize the values of the dropdown in the blade file?

Comment: Were you successful in adding a selected options? I am also trying to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is not a full answer to all of your questions but should help.

1. You can just add a standard select, something like this:

```
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

3. You can get/use that value in `app/Actions/Fortify/CreateNewUser.php` accessing the array. The following inserts the new value into the database:

```
return User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'car' => $input['cars']),
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            'api_token' => Str::random(60),
        ]);
```

You will also need to update the `app/Models/User.php` Model and add the new value as fillable (and of course have added the field to your `User` Model via a migration):

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'car',
    ];
```

Comment: tank you for your answer @Andrew. how can i fill options of select from database? where must be get options from database?

Comment: which file (controller, model, ...) is responsible to load register.blade.php? how i have to fill options of select from database on that file?